# jQuery to PHP data transfer

Tags: php, jquery

Having following jQuery file

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
         var urlform = "register/ajax";
    $("#btnRegister").click( function() {
        $("#Register").submit( function() {
           return false;    
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: urlform,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            async: true,
            data: $("#Register").serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                $("#email").css("border-color", "green");
                $("#rCheck").text(data);
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                $("#email").css("border-color", "red");
                $("#rCheck").text(data);
                console.log(data);
            }
        }); 
    });
});
```

In console log i get

```
Object {email_reg: Object, confirm_password_reg: Object}
    confirm_password_reg: Object
         notSame: "Passwords Doesn't Match"
    __proto__: Object
    email_reg: Object
        recordFound: "E-mail address already exists"
    __proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
```

For more clear interpretation there is following link:.

[image]

But when transfering data in div using **$("#rCheck").text(data);** it gets only **[object Object]**.

**Problem** How to transfer only error messages like:

- Passwords Doesn't Match
- E-mail address already exists

**Json Encode**

```
    if (!$form->isValid()){
        // email is invalid; print the reasons
        $json= $form->getMessages();
        $response->setContent(\Zend\Json\Json::encode($json));
    }
    return $response;
```

How here $json can be pun in an array.

Comment: The returned data is a Javascript objet. You need to extract the field you want, like `data.confirm_password_reg.notSame`.

Comment: You should probably change your JSON so that the result is easier to process. Make it an array instead of an object, and put the error messages in a consistent property in the sub-arrays.

Comment: the problems is `data` is an object, which when passes to `.text()` will print its `.toString()` version that is `[object Object]`

Comment: so try `var msgs = $.map(data, function (key, fieldObj) {
    return [$.map(fieldObj, function (key, msg) {
        return msg;
    })]
});
$('#abc').html(msgs.join('<br />'))`

Comment: also move `$("#Register").submit( function() {..});` out of the click handler

Comment: Please learn more about objects and properties http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_properties.asp https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: @Barmar messages are different depending on validator. Also i added how i encoded JSON. How can i make an array out of this?

Comment: @Arun P Johny i tried what you wrote but it returns numbers to php.

Comment: It's fine for the messages to be different, but the **keys** should be the same, so that the Javascript can find them easily.

Comment: @user3904245 I messed up the order of params so `var msgs = $.map(data, function (fieldObj, key) {
    return [$.map(fieldObj, function (msg, key) {
        return msg;
    })]
});
$('#abc').html(msgs.join('<br />'))`

Comment: @ArunPJohny If you're going to post long code, put it in an answer.

Comment: @ArunPJohny thank you very much this is what i needed. You may also put your code in answer so when someone will look, they won't need to read all comments.

Comment: @user3904245 if there are no errors then what is the value of `data`?

Comment: I added additional post with issue then deleted because figured out how to make it work. If there are no error value of data is null and .map for null gave error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problems is `data` is an object, which when passes to `.text()` will print its `.toString()` version that is `[object Object]`.

so try

```
if (data) {
    var msgs = $.map(data, function (fieldObj, key) {
        return [$.map(fieldObj, function (msg, key) {
            return msg;
        })]
    });
    $('#abc').html(msgs.join('<br />'))
} else {
    //do something
}
```